# Ubuntu graphic card issue: game stuck on loading screen - is there something comparable to this windows solution?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, games

I am playing the game Medieval 2 . The game is stuck on loading screen so there is a comparable solution to this solution for windows:

```
OK, so my initial hunch was actually correct, this problem is related to graphic driver's TDR function. However, I initially didn't apply the setting correctly, because the article I read says 64b OS should set QWORD. Here is what I did to disable TDR, my system is Windows 7:

Open regedit, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/ControlSet001/Control/GraphicsDrivers

Create a new REG_DWORD: TdrLevel, set it to 0

reboot to let new key take effect
```